# bash, get all last files with first 3 same chars from begin in the name of file

Tags: bash, files

**Question**

How to get all last files with first 3 same chars from begin in the name of file?

**I have**

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv (newest)
new-file1.csv
new-file2.csv (newest)
new-file3.csv
```

**I need**

```
file3.csv (newest)
new-file2.csv (newest)
```

I tried loop with array, conditions entered manually with `ls -t`, but what about simple loop which do it by itself? Scan all files and get all files? Is possible to do it only with `for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c1-6 | sort | uniq); do ls -t $i* | head -1; done` command?

Thanks.

Comment: please define `newest` and/or `last` statements plus the relation of first 3 characters in file names with these statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way.

```
# find last file by 6 first chars, copy to archive
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c1-6 | sort | uniq)
do
    cp $(ls -t $i* | head -1) $path/archive | head -1
done
```

Thank you all.

Comment: `time ./script.sh` or `time (echo test)` is your best friend...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the leading name up to the digits, you can use *digit* as *divider*. It puts the leading name in `$1` and the extension in `$NF`(if you piece them together you get, file.csv or new-file.csv).

```
ls -t | awk -F '[0-9]' '!seen[$1$NF]++' | xargs cp -vt $path/archive --
```

Sorting *epoch*; seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, which gives a reverse order fewer seconds, equals to older objects. It will inevitably sort the timestamp opposite the filename.

```
find -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%P\0' \
  | sort -z -k1rn | cut -z -f2- \
  | awk -F '[0-9]' 'BEGIN {RS=ORS="\0"} !seen[$1$NF]++' | xargs -0 -n 1
```

<sup>... or sorting in reverse gives you `sort -rz -k1n`</sup>